# Preventing PHP from auto parsing XML

Tags: html, xml

I'm making an api call to a site using the code as shown below :

```
 $xmlData = file_get_contents("http://isbndb.com/api/books.xml?access_key=XXXXXX&index1=isbn&value1=0596002068");

 echo $xmlData;
```

However xmlData when displayed on the browser is auto parsed to HTML. For e.g. The  element `<title>` of the returned XML which is actually a book title is converted to HTML essentially becoming the page title, and the other XML elements are displayed as plain text without the tags. I want the client side `XMLHttpRequest` Object to get raw XML data from the server side.

Why does this happen and how do I ensure that XML is not auto parsed?

Comment: You just want to display the raw XML on the page, right?

Comment: put it between pre tags.

Comment: @Rocket : Yes, that's what I want.

Comment: Are you sure its not just the browser parsing it?

Comment: `PHP` doesn't do that .. the browser does.  You can use `htmlspecialcharacters` on the xml data.

Comment: I wonder what browser XML parsing has in common with XMLHttpRequest object processing? Did you try to `console.log` AJAX response data? Does it have its 'title' set to something?

Comment: @raina77ow : They don't have anything in common. I assumed that, but it was a wrong assumption. It was actually the browser interpreting the returned data as HTML. Using the `htmlspecialchars`function solved my problem.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

PHP just sees it as text. For instance, do `echo "<b>Bold</b>";` and it will "automatically" be in bold. It is the browser that processes the HTML and renders it.

This is what [`htmlspecialchars`](http://php.net/htmlspecialchars) is for.

Comment: not really. by using `htmlspecialchars()` you alter data you are sending. by setting right content-type you tells the other end what it is.

Comment: That's two different problems - getting the raw data is already working, *displaying* it would require `htmlspecialchars`. Plus, there's always `htmlspecialchars_decode` to undo the change.

Comment: Partially true - displaying it with text/html content type (which is usually send to the browser unless you enforce anything else) would require `htmlspecialchars()`. But setting content-type to `text/plain` would not.

Answer (score 1):

This got nothing to do with php. you spit out elements which browser interprets as HTML (that's why it sets title). Build your html page right, use `<pre>` tags around your content, or. when needed, send your content with correct content-type header (like `text/plain` to display your xml for viewing or `text/xml` for other purposes) so it will not parse your data as html.

Comment: `text/plain` is actually wrong content-type for xml. `application/xml` is better.

Comment: `-1`... Try doing `<pre><b>Hi there</b></pre>`

Comment: Yes, but it was just example (edited anyway). Text/plain would prevent parsing it so he can see the content unprocessed, but if you need one use `text/xml`

Comment: Hi, your approach doesn't work. Setting content type as `text/xml` and using <pre> doesn't seem to affect the way the browser interprets the returned XML data. However using `htmlspecialchars` solves the problem.